# How to keep app open after bash command started C#

Tags: c#, linux, bash, mono

I have a problem with my code on linux. How do I keep app open after some bash commands are launched?
This code:

```
Process.Start("/bin/bash", " -c 'screen -S testScreen -d -m bash -c  \"/home/test/Launcher.exe\"'");
Console.ReadKey();
```

What it does? it runs "Launcher.exe" in "testScreen", but for some reason, it closes program where that bit of code is there. I have there `Console.ReadKey()` in purpose and don't want to close it. Can someone explain me why does it close?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Proces.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-2.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_) method returns an object of type `Process`. After starting the bash command you can invoke [`WaitForExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netcore-2.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_WaitForExit) on it.

```
var proc = Process.Start(...);
proc.WaitForExit();
Console.ReadKey();
```